# process.nexttick throws error - mongoose and mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I've found a couple of similar questions on here with no answers that actually worked for me.  I've created a new node app using npm init.  I installed mongoose and mongodb using npm install.  I have npm installed in the parent folder.  When I run node server.js, I get the following errors in Git Bash.  I have looked all over and can't find an answer.  I honestly don't even understand the stack trace.  I don't know where module.js is.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Did everything install cleanly? Does MongoDB start fine?

Comment: The instance of MongoDB I'm using is hosted on MongoLab.  I have the connection URL stored in config/database.js:

Comment: Okay...but definitely erase that comment. It has your database instance, username and password. :) Did mongoose install without errors?

Comment: It didn't.  The errors it raised were over Visual Studio versions.  Some of the other folders in the repo have VS solution files in them.  I know I've got my U:P up there.  I considered that, but it only has one database in it and this is a public project with a few members, so I left the connection string in case someone needed to test with it.

Answer (score 0):

I found my solution, and it sure was simple.  For this particular project, I'm connecting to a mongolab hosted instance of MongoDB.  I had the password wrong in the connection string.  I was using my login password and not my database password.  That's what I get for using the same username for both.

```
moongoose.connect('mongodb://<dbuser>:<dbpassword>@ds061731.mongolab.com:61731/mongocrud
```

I had my user account information in the dbuser and dbpassword fields.  A simple fix, but tough to find with the given stack trace.  I set up another simple project with just the mongo pieces that I need and found the connection error very quickly.